# Change push menu to overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, modernizr

I am trying to implement this slide menu to my project ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sanjeevks121/ps855n8r/)) but the problem is, when you click on menu icon, its pushing the whole page to right, but I am trying to overlay it instead of pushing to right, is it possible with this plugin? Can anyone please look and suggest?

thanks

(Please look at [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sanjeevks121/ps855n8r/) link, I have copied here CSS only)

```css
*,
*:after,
*::before {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body, .container, .scroller {
height: 100%;
}

.scroller {
overflow-y: scroll;
}

.scroller,
.scroller-inner {
position: relative;
}

.container {
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
background: #34495e;
}

.menu-trigger {
position: relative;
padding-left: 60px;
font-size: 0.9em;
}

.menu-trigger:before {
position: absolute;
top: 2px;
left: 0;
width: 40px;
height: 6px;
background: #fff;
box-shadow: 0 6px #34495e, 0 12px #fff, 0 18px #34495e, 0 24px #fff;
content: '';
}

.mp-pusher {
position: relative;
left: 0;
height: 100%;
}

.mp-menu {
position: absolute; /* we can't use fixed here :( */
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 1;
width: 300px;
height: 100%;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
-moz-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
}

.mp-level {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: #336ca6;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
-moz-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
}

/* overlays for pusher and for level that gets covered */
.mp-pusher::after,
.mp-level::after,
.mp-level::before {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
width: 0;
height: 0;
content: '';
opacity: 0;
}

.mp-pusher::after,
.mp-level::after {
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s, width 0.1s 0.3s, height 0.1s 0.3s;
-moz-transition: opacity 0.3s, width 0.1s 0.3s, height 0.1s 0.3s;
transition: opacity 0.3s, width 0.1s 0.3s, height 0.1s 0.3s;
}

.mp-level::after {
z-index: -1;
}

.mp-pusher.mp-pushed::after,
.mp-level.mp-level-overlay::after {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s;
-moz-transition: opacity 0.3s;
transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.mp-level.mp-level-overlay {
cursor: pointer;
}

.mp-level.mp-level-overlay.mp-level::before {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: transparent;
opacity: 1;
}

.mp-pusher,
.mp-level {
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s;
transition: all 0.5s;
}

/* overlap */
.mp-overlap .mp-level.mp-level-open {
box-shadow: 1px 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
-webkit-transform: translate3d(-40px, 0, 0);
-moz-transform: translate3d(-40px, 0, 0);
transform: translate3d(-40px, 0, 0);
}

/* First level */
.mp-menu > .mp-level,
.mp-menu > .mp-level.mp-level-open,
.mp-menu.mp-overlap > .mp-level,
.mp-menu.mp-overlap > .mp-level.mp-level-open {
box-shadow: none;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

/* cover */
.mp-cover .mp-level.mp-level-open {
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.mp-cover .mp-level.mp-level-open > ul > li > .mp-level:not(.mp-level-open) {
-webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
-moz-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
}

/* content style */
.mp-menu ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
}

.mp-menu h2 {
margin: 0;
padding: 1em;
color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
font-weight: 300;
font-size: 2em;
}

.mp-menu.mp-overlap h2::before {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
margin-right: 8px;
font-size: 75%;
line-height: 1.8;
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s, -webkit-transform 0.1s 0.3s;
-moz-transition: opacity 0.3s, -moz-transform 0.1s 0.3s;
transition: opacity 0.3s, transform 0.1s 0.3s;
-webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
-moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.mp-menu.mp-cover h2 {
text-transform: uppercase;
font-weight: 700;
letter-spacing: 1px;
font-size: 1em;
}

.mp-overlap .mp-level.mp-level-overlay > h2::before {
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
-moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
transition: transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
-webkit-transform: translateX(0);
-moz-transform: translateX(0);
transform: translateX(0);
}

.mp-menu ul li > a {
display: block;
padding: 0.7em 1em 0.7em 1.8em;
outline: none;
box-shadow: inset 0 -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
font-size: 1.4em;
-webkit-transition: background 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
-moz-transition: background 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
transition: background 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
}

.mp-menu ul li::before {
position: absolute;
left: 10px;
z-index: -1;
color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
line-height: 3.5;
}

.mp-level > ul > li:first-child > a {
box-shadow: inset 0 -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), inset 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.mp-menu ul li a:hover,
.mp-level > ul > li:first-child > a:hover {
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
box-shadow: inset 0 -1px rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

.mp-menu .mp-level.mp-level-overlay > ul > li > a,
.mp-level.mp-level-overlay > ul > li:first-child > a {
box-shadow: inset 0 -1px rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

.mp-level > ul > li:first-child > a:hover,
.mp-level.mp-level-overlay > ul > li:first-child > a {
box-shadow: inset 0 -1px rgba(0,0,0,0), inset 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0);
} /* seems like Chrome 34.0.1847.131 needs the second shadow otherwise the transition breaks */

.mp-back {
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
outline: none;
color: #fff;
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: 1px;
font-weight: 700;
display: block;
font-size: 0.8em;
padding: 1em;
position: relative;
box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
-webkit-transition: background 0.3s;
-moz-transition: background 0.3s;
transition: background 0.3s;
}

.mp-back::after {
font-family: 'linecons';
position: absolute;
content: "\e037";
right: 10px;
font-size: 1.3em;
color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.mp-menu .mp-level.mp-level-overlay > .mp-back,
.mp-menu .mp-level.mp-level-overlay > .mp-back::after {
background: transparent;
box-shadow: none;
color: transparent;
}

/* Fallback example for browsers that don't support 3D transforms (and no JS fallback) */
/* We'll show the first level only */
.no-csstransforms3d .mp-pusher,
.no-js .mp-pusher {
padding-left: 300px;
}

.no-csstransforms3d .mp-menu .mp-level,
.no-js .mp-menu .mp-level {
display: none;
}

.no-csstransforms3d .mp-menu > .mp-level,
.no-js .mp-menu > .mp-level {
display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Check the updated fiddle.I have changed the translation on the mp-pusher to Nav with id mp-menu

```
    //this._setTransform( 'translate3d(' + translateVal + 'px,0,0)' );

    this._setTransform( 'translate3d(0px,0,0)' ,this.el);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ps855n8r/1/

Comment: Yes, seems to be working but it has lost the sliding effects :(

Comment: transition: all 0.5s; this to .mp-menu  in css.Hope this helps.check the fiddle now

Answer (score 0):

replace this css

```
.mp-pusher {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) !important;
}

.mp-pushed .mp-menu{left:300px}
```

Comment: at which line, I tried replacing but menu stopped opening on click

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
*,
*:after,
*::before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body, .container, .scroller {
    height: 100%;
}

.scroller {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.scroller,
.scroller-inner {
    position: relative;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #34495e;
}

.menu-trigger {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 60px;
    font-size: 0.9em;
}

.menu-trigger:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    left: 0;
    width: 40px;
    height: 6px;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 6px #34495e, 0 12px #fff, 0 18px #34495e, 0 24px #fff;
    content: '';
}

.mp-pusher {
      position: relative;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) !important;
}

.mp-menu {
    position: absolute; /* we can't use fixed here :( */
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
}
.mp-pushed .mp-menu{left:300px}

.mp-level {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #336ca6;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
}

/* overlays for pusher and for level that gets covered */
.mp-pusher::after,
.mp-level::after,
.mp-level::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    content: '';
    opacity: 0;
}

.mp-pusher::after,
.mp-level::after {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s, width 0.1s 0.3s, height 0.1s 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s, width 0.1s 0.3s, height 0.1s 0.3s;
    transition: opacity 0.3s, width 0.1s 0.3s, height 0.1s 0.3s;
}

.mp-level::after {
    z-index: -1;
}

.mp-pusher.mp-pushed::after,
.mp-level.mp-level-overlay::after {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.mp-level.mp-level-overlay {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.mp-level.mp-level-overlay.mp-level::before {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: transparent;
    opacity: 1;
}

.mp-pusher,
.mp-level {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

/* overlap */
.mp-overlap .mp-level.mp-level-open {
    box-shadow: 1px 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-40px, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(-40px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-40px, 0, 0);
}

/* First level */
.mp-menu > .mp-level,
.mp-menu > .mp-level.mp-level-open,
.mp-menu.mp-overlap > .mp-level,
.mp-menu.mp-overlap > .mp-level.mp-level-open {
    box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

/* cover */
.mp-cover .mp-level.mp-level-open {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.mp-cover .mp-level.mp-level-open > ul > li > .mp-level:not(.mp-level-open) {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
}

/* content style */
.mp-menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.mp-menu h2 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1em;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 2em;
}

.mp-menu.mp-overlap h2::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-right: 8px;
    font-size: 75%;
    line-height: 1.8;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s, -webkit-transform 0.1s 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s, -moz-transform 0.1s 0.3s;
    transition: opacity 0.3s, transform 0.1s 0.3s;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
    transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.mp-menu.mp-cover h2 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: 1em;
}

.mp-overlap .mp-level.mp-level-overlay > h2::before {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
    transition: transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
}

.mp-menu ul li > a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0.7em 1em 0.7em 1.8em;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    font-size: 1.4em;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: background 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
    transition: background 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
}

.mp-menu ul li::before {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    z-index: -1;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    line-height: 3.5;
}

.mp-level > ul > li:first-child > a {
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), inset 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.mp-menu ul li a:hover,
.mp-level > ul > li:first-child > a:hover {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

.mp-menu .mp-level.mp-level-overlay > ul > li > a,
.mp-level.mp-level-overlay > ul > li:first-child > a {
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

.mp-level > ul > li:first-child > a:hover,
.mp-level.mp-level-overlay > ul > li:first-child > a {
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px rgba(0,0,0,0), inset 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0);
} /* seems like Chrome 34.0.1847.131 needs the second shadow otherwise the transition breaks */

.mp-back {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    outline: none;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: 700;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    padding: 1em;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    -webkit-transition: background 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: background 0.3s;
    transition: background 0.3s;
}

.mp-back::after {
    font-family: 'linecons';
    position: absolute;
    content: "\e037";
    right: 10px;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.mp-menu .mp-level.mp-level-overlay > .mp-back,
.mp-menu .mp-level.mp-level-overlay > .mp-back::after {
    background: transparent;
    box-shadow: none;
    color: transparent;
}

/* Fallback example for browsers that don't support 3D transforms (and no JS fallback) */
/* We'll show the first level only */
.no-csstransforms3d .mp-pusher,
.no-js .mp-pusher {
    padding-left: 300px;
}

.no-csstransforms3d .mp-menu .mp-level,
.no-js .mp-menu .mp-level {
    display: none;
}

.no-csstransforms3d .mp-menu > .mp-level,
.no-js .mp-menu > .mp-level {
    display: block;
}

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700);
@font-face {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-family: 'codropsicons';
    src:url('../fonts/codropsicons/codropsicons.eot');
    src:url('../fonts/codropsicons/codropsicons.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../fonts/codropsicons/codropsicons.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../fonts/codropsicons/codropsicons.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('../fonts/codropsicons/codropsicons.svg#codropsicons') format('svg');
}

body {
    background: #34495e;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-family: 'Lato', Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #f7f7f7;
    outline: none;
}

a:hover, a:focus {
    color: #fff;
    outline: none;
}

/* Clearfix hack by Nicolas Gallagher: http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/ */
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    display: table;
    content: " ";
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}

.codrops-header,
.codrops-top {
    font-family: 'Lato', Arial, sans-serif;
}

.codrops-header {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 2em;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.01);
    text-align: center;
}

.codrops-header h1 {
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 2.625em;
    line-height: 1.3;
}

.codrops-header span {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 0 0.6em 0.1em;
    font-size: 60%;
    opacity: 0.7;
}

/* To Navigation Style */
.codrops-top {
    width: 100%;
    background: #91cfa1;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 0.69em;
    line-height: 2.2;
}

.codrops-top a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 1em;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}

.codrops-top a:hover {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.95);
    color: #333;
}

.codrops-top span.right {
    float: right;
}

.codrops-top span.right a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

.codrops-icon:before {
    margin: 0 4px;
    text-transform: none;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-family: 'codropsicons';
    line-height: 1;
    speak: none;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.codrops-icon-drop:before {
    content: "\e001";
}

.codrops-icon-prev:before {
    content: "\e004";
}

/* Demo Buttons Style */
.codrops-demos {
    padding-top: 1em;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}

.codrops-demos a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    margin: 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em 1.9em;
    padding: 1em 1.1em;
    width: 280px;
    outline: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: #336ca6;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.codrops-demos a:hover,
.codrops-demos a.current-demo,
.codrops-demos a.current-demo:hover {
    opacity: 0.6;
}

.content {
    padding: 4em 2em;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.block {
    float: left;
    padding: 1em 3em;
}

.block-40 {
    width: 40%;
}

.block-60 {
    width: 60%;
}

.block p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 1em 0.6em;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

.info {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin-top: 3em;
    clear: both;
    padding-top: 3em;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}

.info a {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 0.9em;
}

.info a:hover {
    color: #336ca6;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 69em) {
    .block {
        float: none;
        width: 100% !important;
        padding: 1em;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 25em) {

    body {
        font-size: 80%;
    }

    .codrops-icon span {
        display: none;
    }

}
```